# Rails 3.2 : Duplicate entry for key index in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am using rails 3.2. Here! I am facing a problem, stats below.

I am having two model classes RequestedTrip and TagTrip. Here! are two other models RequestedTripAgent and Tag on which I operate in before_save callback of RequestedTrip and after_update callback of TagTrip.

There is a case in which I am facing Duplicate entry problem. The case is ...

I am updating RequestedTrip object. There is a before_save callback in which I am using find_or_create_by to find or create RequestedTripAgent object. I also assigning Tags to RequestedTrip object through which another callbacks fire in TagTrip after_update. In TagTrip after_update callback, I also using find_or_create_by of same object of RequestedTripAgent.

Here I am using find_or_create_by but getting Duplicate key index error for RequestedTripAgent. What is wrong with me?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, Rails 3.2 is over 5 years old. When it was released, Siri was brand new, Kim Jong Il was still the head of North Korea, and Lyft hadn't launched yet. It's no longer supported by the Rails team and can no longer be considered secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_or_create_by` in `before_save` is probably creating the resource and again after the callback it is trying to save the same resource..either move everything to `after_save` or replace it with `.first_or_initialize`.

Comment: Already, I have used same '.first_or_initialize_by' but did not work!